# Ruby: error -2740 when run system command

Tags: ruby, command-line, rubygems

I am trying to run this command:

```
system("osascript -e \"tell application \"Finder\" to set desktop picture to POSIX file \"#{enterprise_logo_url}"\" ")
```

This should change the background from a mac screen automatically. The command works itself on the CLI, but when I run it under ruby it says:

```
syntax error: A class name can’t go after this application constant or consideration. (-2740)
```

I am not really sure how to read this error... I did some research on internet but found nothing related to this kind of error.

Any idea why?

Comment: This is not a Ruby error message. You will have to look up the documentation of whatever program is generating that error.

Comment: This is pure command line. It works in your command line. So I don't think it comes from whatever program, since there is not

Comment: It is *not* an error message from Ruby. It *must* come from somewhere else. Probably from `osascript`, since that is the only other program involved here. You will have to look up the syntax of AppleScript, in order to figure out what is wrong with your program, since the syntax error is in your AppleScript code, not in your Ruby code.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer to this topic.

`system("osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to set picture of every desktop to (\"#{path}\" as POSIX file as alias)' ")`

If for whatever reason you have to change the background through ruby, and it's a new High Sierra OS, this command will do the trick for you.

Comment: Please, add an explanation as to what the problem is and how this answer fixes the problem. As it stands now, the answer is not helpful.